# SonarQube upgrade 4.2 -> 4.3.2 UpdateMeasuresDebtToMinutes appears hung

Tags: configuration, installation, migration, sonarqube

When upgrading SonarQube 4.2 to 4.3.2 on Windows 7 Enterprise / SQL Server 2012 / Java 7 Update 51 64bit JDK

The setup screen stated:

SonarQube Database is currenly upgrading.

Started about 22 hours ago (14 Jul 2014 11:45)

The sonar.log file is as follows:

```
--> Wrapper Started as Console

Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2014.07.14 11:42:31 INFO  [o.s.a.Connectors]  HTTP connector is enabled on port 9000
2014.07.14 11:42:32 INFO  [o.a.c.h.Http11Protocol]  Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2014.07.14 11:42:32 INFO  [o.a.c.c.StandardService]  Starting service Tomcat
2014.07.14 11:42:32 INFO  [o.a.c.c.StandardEngine]  Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
2014.07.14 11:42:32 INFO  [o.a.c.s.ContextConfig]  No global web.xml found
2014.07.14 11:42:33 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ServerImpl]  SonarQube Server / 4.3.2 / a82ddddad45acebdce81bdf70767a4ee11147392
2014.07.14 11:42:33 INFO  [o.s.c.p.Database]  Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/sonardb;SelectMethod=Cursor
2014.07.14 11:42:34 INFO  [o.s.s.p.DatabaseServerCompatibility]  Database must be upgraded. Please browse /setup
2014.07.14 11:42:34 INFO  [o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem]  SonarQube home: C:\sonarqube-4.3.2
2014.07.14 11:42:34 INFO  [o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem]  Deploy dir: C:\sonarqube-4.3.2\web\deploy
2014.07.14 11:42:34 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Install plugins...
2014.07.14 11:42:34 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Findbugs / 2.3 / a231b7d2488255a3494a8704d8ebd3e92af7d0bf
2014.07.14 11:42:34 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Timeline / 1.4 / 5dbb36d5db80475315f3f39ac3ec506ef92a9d6a
2014.07.14 11:42:34 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Build Stability / 1.2 / 2b32f73fbe180e8b5b6f56271018e3b0cd2c477d
2014.07.14 11:42:34 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Clirr / 1.1
2014.07.14 11:42:34 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin English Pack / 4.3.2 / a82ddddad45acebdce81bdf70767a4ee11147392
2014.07.14 11:42:34 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin SCM Activity / 1.7.1 / 233895448799dc2ab0274aa518a77cc1b93fed7f
2014.07.14 11:42:34 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Duplications / 4.3.2 / a82ddddad45acebdce81bdf70767a4ee11147392
2014.07.14 11:42:34 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Doxygen / 0.1 / 6014
2014.07.14 11:42:34 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin PMD / 2.2 / a5da0c1cde1bd7be862a09dbb743fd9367c849d6
2014.07.14 11:42:34 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Squid for Java / 2.3 / a231b7d2488255a3494a8704d8ebd3e92af7d0bf
2014.07.14 11:42:34 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Email notifications / 4.3.2 / a82ddddad45acebdce81bdf70767a4ee11147392
2014.07.14 11:42:34 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Motion Chart / 1.7 / e9c4a5c95c75564b3c3b5a887b63ef50fc59a156
2014.07.14 11:42:34 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin JavaScript / 1.6 / 854b85c280793d4f983742a37b33b0449e2a65d4
2014.07.14 11:42:34 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Security Rules / 0.3.2
2014.07.14 11:42:34 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin XML / 1.2 / 8a0e3c61b4bf3568125302a7ac87d677e8566c1f
2014.07.14 11:42:34 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin JaCoCo / 2.3 / a231b7d2488255a3494a8704d8ebd3e92af7d0bf
2014.07.14 11:42:35 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Widget Lab / 1.4.1 / f4e93e520bbecc47db57d42010c8fd267bb6e675
2014.07.14 11:42:35 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Scm Stats / 0.3.1 / fd4f129d8cc73da085723c50b94936d74b1dc975
2014.07.14 11:42:35 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Maven Batch Plugin / 4.3.2 / a82ddddad45acebdce81bdf70767a4ee11147392
2014.07.14 11:42:35 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Surefire / 2.3 / a231b7d2488255a3494a8704d8ebd3e92af7d0bf
2014.07.14 11:42:35 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Tab Metrics / 1.4 / fa240469a783a0fe5b76c752ed014add30a346df
2014.07.14 11:42:35 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Checkstyle / 2.1 / 219b216223e3e2477d1588064f25fca77be922a9
2014.07.14 11:42:35 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Java / 2.3 / a231b7d2488255a3494a8704d8ebd3e92af7d0bf
2014.07.14 11:42:35 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Core / 4.3.2 / a82ddddad45acebdce81bdf70767a4ee11147392
2014.07.14 11:42:35 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Database Cleaner / 4.3.2 / a82ddddad45acebdce81bdf70767a4ee11147392
2014.07.14 11:42:35 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Cobertura / 1.6.2 / 97fa42dd2ec9396debeeee6622eaa1df59e71f12
2014.07.14 11:42:35 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Design / 4.3.2 / a82ddddad45acebdce81bdf70767a4ee11147392
2014.07.14 11:42:35 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Install plugins done: 405 ms
2014.07.14 11:42:35 INFO  [o.s.s.p.RailsAppsDeployer]  Deploy Ruby on Rails applications
2014.07.14 11:42:35 INFO  [o.s.s.p.RailsAppsDeployer]  Deploy app: motionchart
2014.07.14 11:42:35 INFO  [jruby.rack]  jruby 1.7.9 (ruby-1.8.7p370) 2013-12-06 87b108a on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_51-b13 [Windows 7-amd64]
2014.07.14 11:42:35 INFO  [jruby.rack]  using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
2014.07.14 11:42:46 INFO  [jruby.rack]  keeping custom (config.logger) Rails logger instance
Database must be upgraded. Please browse /setup
2014.07.14 11:42:46 INFO  [o.a.c.h.Http11Protocol]  Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2014.07.14 11:42:46 INFO  Web server is started
2014.07.14 11:45:23 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  CreateQualityGates: migrating =============================================
2014.07.14 11:45:23 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- create_table(:quality_gates, {})
2014.07.14 11:45:23 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.0090s
2014.07.14 11:45:23 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
2014.07.14 11:45:23 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- add_index("quality_gates", ["name"], {:unique=>true, :name=>"uniq_quality_gates"})
2014.07.14 11:45:23 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.0450s
2014.07.14 11:45:23 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
2014.07.14 11:45:23 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  CreateQualityGates: migrated (0.0560s) ====================================
2014.07.14 11:45:23 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.07.14 11:45:23 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  CreateQualityGateConditions: migrating ====================================
2014.07.14 11:45:23 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- create_table(:quality_gate_conditions, {})
2014.07.14 11:45:23 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.0050s
2014.07.14 11:45:23 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
2014.07.14 11:45:23 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  CreateQualityGateConditions: migrated (0.0050s) ===========================
2014.07.14 11:45:23 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.07.14 11:45:23 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  ConvertAlertsToQualityGates: migrating ====================================
2014.07.14 11:45:23 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  ConvertAlertsToQualityGates: migrated (0.0730s) ===========================
2014.07.14 11:45:23 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.07.14 11:45:23 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  UpdateIssueDebtToMinutes: migrating =======================================
2014.07.14 11:45:34 INFO  [o.s.s.d.m.MassUpdater]  447217 rows have been updated
2014.07.14 11:45:34 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  UpdateIssueDebtToMinutes: migrated (10.5750s) =============================
2014.07.14 11:45:34 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.07.14 11:45:34 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  UpdateIssueChangelogDebtToMinutes: migrating ==============================
2014.07.14 11:45:35 INFO  [o.s.s.d.m.MassUpdater]  39 rows have been updated
2014.07.14 11:45:35 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  UpdateIssueChangelogDebtToMinutes: migrated (1.0090s) =====================
2014.07.14 11:45:35 INFO  [DbMigration]  
2014.07.14 11:45:35 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  UpdateMeasuresDebtToMinutes: migrating ====================================
```

**Running a SQL Server Trace the only database activity that appears is a 'SELECT 1' every few seconds**

**Reviewed SQL Activity Monitor and noted the following SQL Statements where blocking:**

**SQL Process: 56 blocked by 56**

```
SELECT pm.id, pm.value , pm.variation_value_1 , pm.variation_value_2, pm.variation_value_3 , pm.variation_value_4 , pm.variation_value_5  FROM project_measures pm INNER JOIN metrics m on m.id=pm.metric_id  WHERE (m.name='sqale_index' or m.name='new_technical_debt'  or m.name='sqale_effort_to_grade_a' or m.name='sqale_effort_to_grade_b' or m.name='sqale_effort_to_grade_c' or m.name='sqale_effort_to_grade_d'  or m.name='blocker_remediation_cost' or m.name='critical_remediation_cost' or m.name='major_remediation_cost' or m.name='minor_remediation_cost'  or m.name='info_remediation_cost' )
```

**SQL Process: 58 blocked by 56**

```
(@P0 float,@P1 float,@P2 float,@P3 float,@P4 float,@P5 float,@P6 bigint)UPDATE project_measures SET value= @P0 ,variation_value_1= @P1 ,variation_value_2= @P2 ,variation_value_3= @P3 ,variation_value_4= @P4 ,variation_value_5= @P5  WHERE id= @P6
```

**After waiting for 22+ Hours killed SQL process 58 and noted the following stacktace in the sonar.log:**

```
2014.07.15 10:13:50 INFO  [o.s.s.d.m.MassUpdater]  8000 rows have been updated
2014.07.15 10:13:50 ERROR [o.s.s.d.m.DatabaseMigrator]  Fail to execute database migration: org.sonar.server.db.migrations.v43.TechnicalDebtMeasuresMigration
org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: Fail to migrate data, error is : The server returned an unspecified error.
```

Can anyone tell me if the upgrade had in fact hung or is it just slow, has anyone else encountered this and if so how was it resolved.

I have reviewed a similar post for this issue when upgrading from 4.2 to 4.3 but I am upgrading to 4.3.2, in which I thought this issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue myself by applying the following database indexes:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [exelidx_metric_id]
ON [dbo].[project_measures] ([metric_id])
INCLUDE ([id],[value],[variation_value_1],[variation_value_2],[variation_value_3],[variation_value_4],[variation_value_5])
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [exelidx_characteristic_id]
ON [dbo].[project_measures] ([characteristic_id])
INCLUDE ([id])
GO
```

Upgrade completed sucessfully in 8 minutes.