# Upgrade to SonarQube 4.5.1 fails at UpdateMeasuresDebtToMinutes

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5, sonarqube-4.0

I am trying to update from 4.0 to 4.5.1 but the process always fails at `UpdateMeasuresDebtToMinutes`. I am using MySQL 5.5.27 as a database with InnoDB as table engine.

Basically the problem looks like [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24756781/sonarqube-upgrade-4-2-4-3-2-updatemeasuresdebttominutes-appears-hung)

After the writeTimeout exceeds (600 seconds) there is an exception in the log

```
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 81 bytes, read 15 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3166) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3676) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
```

Adding the indexes as proposed in the linked issue did not help.

Investigating further I noticed several things:

- the migration step reads data from a table and wants to write back to the same table (`project_measures`)
- project_measures contains more than 770000 rows
- the process always hangs after 249 rows
- the hanging happens in `org.sonar.server.migrations.MassUpdate` when calling `update.addBatch()` which after the `BatchSession.MAX_BATCH_SIZE (250)` forces an execute and a commit

is there a way to configure the DB connection to allow this to proceed?

Comment: When you say that it fails, don't you have any error in the logs?

Comment: yes sure .. the same as in the linked issue, after exceeding a timeout there is an java.io.EOFException .. will add a snippet to the text above

Answer (score 0):

First of all, could you try to revert your db to 4.0 and try again ?
Then, could you please give us the JDBC url (sonar.jdbc.url) you're using ?

Thanks

Comment: Reverting just leads to the same problem, again and again and again .. As jdbc URL I tried several versions with different timeout settings, but those just change the moment when the exception is logged. Right now i use this setting `sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance`

Answer (score 0):

As I need that sonar server to run I finally implemented a workaround.

It seems I cannot write to the database at all, as long as a big result set is still open (I tried with a second table but the same issue as before).

Therefore I changed all migrations that need to read and write the `project_measures`table (`org.sonar.server.db.migrations.v43.TechnicalDebtMeasuresMigration`, `org.sonar.server.db.migrations.v43.RequirementMeasuresMigration`, `org.sonar.server.db.migrations.v44.MeasureDataMigration`) to load the changed data into a memory structure and after closing the read resultset write it back. 
This is as hacky as it sounds and will not work for larger datasets where you would need to this with paging through the data or storing everything into a secondary datastore.

Furthermore I found that later on (in `546_inverse_rule_key_index.rb`) an index needs to be created on the `rules` table which is larger than the max key length on mysql (2 varchar(255) columns with UTF-8 is more than 1000bytes .. ) so I had to limit the key length on that too ..

As I said, it is a workaround and therefore I will not accept it as an answer ..

Comment: FYI the max length of rule index is supposed to be managed for mysql. It is truncated to the maximum supported length.